# Typing a property getter function for an Angular component input

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm struggling with typing a function for Angular. Even if the solution you'll see is suboptimal from Angular perspective, I'd still be curious to know how to properly provide the function type for a good Dx of the component consumers.

MyComponent (imagine a select component) accepts two Inputs:

```
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() items: (object | string)[] = [];
  @Input() idGetterFn: OptionIdGetterFn = ...
}
```

The `items` will obviously hold an array of items, and I want to allow strings as well as objects. The component needs to know how to get item identifier. In case of strings it will be an identity function, in case of objects - a function that returns a string from among the `keyof` the object.

I tried with the following `OptionIdGetterFn` type:

```
export type OptionIdGetter = <T extends (string | object)>(item: T) =>
  T extends object ? keyof T & string : T;
```

Unfortunately, TypeScript doesn't like it when I try to initialize a default identity function:

```
@Input() idGetterFn: OptionIdGetterFn = item => item;


Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T extends object ? keyof T & string : T'.
```

```
@Input() idGetterFn: OptionIdGetterFn = (item: string) => item;


Type '(item: string) => string' is not assignable to type 'OptionIdGetterFn'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'string | object' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

```
@Input() idGetterFn: OptionIdGetterFn = (item: { _id: string }) => item._id;


Type '(item: { id: string;}) => string' is not assignable to type 'OptionIdGetterFn'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'item' are incompatible.
     Type 'T' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
       Type 'string | object' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
         Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ id: string; }'.
```

How do I properly type this function?